# How do I set up the azure truffle boxes?

Tags: truffle, truffle-box, azure

Hi I was looking through the newly added azure-boxes on [truffle boxes](https://truffleframework.com/boxes) such as the [azure-simple-marketplace-box](https://github.com/truffle-box/azure-simple-marketplace-box) and was wondering how to set up the front-end for these boxes.

Is it just suppose to be a smart contract that can be deployed to testnets? Or do I need to use use and install azure?

If anyone knows anything please help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truffle boxes are intended for use with [Azure Blockchain Workbench](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/workbench/). You can read more about Truffle on Azure [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sweet-updates-about-truffle-on-azure/).

Comment: Hmm my free trial of azure is about to expire